# scala: mapping future of tuple

Tags: scala

I have a `Future` of `Tuple` like this `Future[(WriteResult, MyObject)] mytuplefuture`, I'd like to map it and do something with `MyObject` so I am doing this:

```
mytuplefuture.map((wr,obj)=>{ //do sth});
```

but my eclipse scala IDE does not allow and recommend me to do:

```
mytuplefuture.map{ case(wr,obj) => { //do sth }}
```

what is the difference between those two?

I am used to doing the first one, I do not know about the second one until I try returning that tuple that wrapped in a future

```
myfuture.map((obj) => { // do sth with obj })
```

it was clear, I am mapping the content of the Future and do something with it, which will return another future because the original myfuture only contains something (obj) in the future..

Would anyone explain please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is this:

`map` is a *higher-order function* (*HOF*) that takes a function as its argument. This function - let's call it the *mapping function* for convenience - itself takes a single argument, which is the value of the completed `Future`. In this particular case, this value happens to be a tuple. Your first attempt assumed that the tuple could be broken open into two arguments, which would then be accepted by the *mapping function* - but that's not going to happen, hence the error.

It might seem that you could define the *mapping function* like this (note the extra parentheses around the arguments):

```
mytuplefuture.map(((wr,obj)) => /* do sth */)
```

however this is not currently supported by the *Scala* compiler. (That said, I *think* this might be a feature of a future *Scala* release.)

So, the alternative is to write the *mapping function* as a *partial function* using the `case` statement. The following:

```
mytuplefuture.map {
  case (wr,obj) => //
}
```

is actually a kind of shorthand for:

```
mytuplefuture.map {
  tuple: (WriteResult, MyObject) => tuple match {
    case (wr,obj) => // do sth
  }
}
```

In fact, this shorthand is generally useful for situations other than just breaking open tuples. For instance:

```
myList.filter {
  case A => true
  case _ => false
}
```

is short for:

```
myList.filter {
  x => x match {
    case A => true
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

So, let's say you wish to look at just the `MyObject` member of the tuple. You would define this as follows:

```
val myfuture = mytuplefuture.map {
  case (_, obj) => obj
}
```

or, alternatively, being explicit with the tuple argument:

```
val myfuture = mytuplefuture.map(tuple => tuple._2)
```

which can in turn be simplified to just:

```
val myfuture = mytuplefuture.map(_._2)
```

where the first underscore is shorthand for the first argument to the *mapping function*. (The second underscore, as in `_2`, is part of the name for the second value in the tuple, and is not shorthand - this is where *Scala* can get a little confusing.)

All of the previous three examples return a `Future[MyObject]`.

If you then apply `map` to this value, the single *mapping function* argument in this case will be your `MyObject` instance. Hence you can now write:

```
myfuture.map(obj => /* Do something with obj */)
```

As to the remainder of your question, the *mapping function* as applied to a `Future`'s value does indeed apply to the result of the original future, since it can't be executed until the first future has completed. Therefore, `map` returns a future that completes (successfully or otherwise) when the first future completes.

**UPDATED**: Clarified what the argument to `map` actually is. Thanks to @AlexeyRomanov for putting me right, and to @RhysBradbury for pointing out my initial error. ;-)

Comment: "map takes a single argument, which in this particular case happens to be a tuple."
This is wrong.... 
Map takes a HOF.

Comment: Both are incorrect. `map` takes a single argument which is a function, which makes `map` itself a higher-order function. This doesn't mean its argument is a higher-order function (though it can be).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Gah! Of course, you're right. `map` is indeed a _HOF_ itself, and its argument is a just a regular single-argument function (which may or may not be a _HOF_). Another rewrite coming up... :-(

Answer (score -1):

The difference is, that `case` indicates decomposition (or extraction) of the object (invoking `unapply`, which you can implement yourself).

`myfuture.map(obj => obj._2 )` in this case obj - is your tuple, so you can access its elements by `._1` and `._2`

`mytuplefuture.map{ case(wr,obj) => { //do sth }}` this decompose tuple to its elements.

You can better feel the difference, by using this approach on `case class` which comes with a default `unapply` implementation

```
case class MyClass(int: Int)
List(MyClass(1)) map { myclass => myclass.int } // accesing the elements
List(MyClass(1)) map { case MyClass(i) => i + 1 } // decomposition
```

In your case I'd write

```
mytuplefuture.map(_.2).map( // do somthing )
```

P.S.
You can do the extraction for many other classes (`Option` for example).
It is also allowing you to write something like

```
val (a, b) = tuple
val MyClass(x) = myclass
```